# How do I downcast_ref and return the reference from a function

Tags: rust

Code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9eb25c03f975cdb8d7c02d896539c071)

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a Container struct that I can add arbitrary components to.
The components can basically have any functionality they want and should have an Rc<RefCell<Container>> so they can access other components.

For convenience I would like the add_component function (and future get_component function) to dohe d towncast internally.

Comment: The code should be embedded in the question, not a link to an external resource.

Comment: Note that using `type_name()` as a component ID is a bad idea. Use [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problematic because while [there is a method in the standard library that downcasts a `Rc<dyn Any>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downcast), there is no such method for `Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>>`. AFAICT, the only way you can do that is by building it yourself with unsafe code:

```rust
fn downcast<T: Any>(v: Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>>) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>> {
    if <dyn Any>::is::<T>(&*v.borrow()) {
        let v: *const RefCell<dyn Any> = Rc::into_raw(v);
        Some(unsafe { Rc::from_raw(v as *const RefCell<T>) })
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Then:

```rust
downcast(Rc::clone(self.borrow().components.get(&comp_name).unwrap())).unwrap()
```

I *believe* this is sound, but I'm not entirely sure because the part where we convert `*const RefCell<dyn Any>` to `*const RefCell<T>` touches some not-documented dark corners.